# Are "how to research a company" questions on-topic anywhere on Stack Exchange?

Tags: discussion, research, site-recommendation

I am researching an advertising company (for a client) to try to figure out how legitimate they are.  Beyond their web site and the claims therein, I found 14 Facebook reviews (all at five stars), nothing incriminating on searches like "(company-name) scam", and nothing on other review sites like Yelp, the Better Business Bureau, and Glassdoor.  In general there was mostly radio silence.  This overall picture seems odd to me and I want to ask about further methods of researching them.

Is there any site on the Stack Exchange network where I can ask a question about this?

Comment: Definitely not Workplace. Something similar to this has been addressed on Personal Finance w/r/t  confirming a company exists and looking up its history and statements, but I'm not sure it meets the goals stated here and I'm not sure the level of detail implied here fits there.